# Using Kronecker's theorem to construct a field with four elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Use Kronecker's theorem to construct a field with four elements by adjoining a suitable root of $x^4-x$ to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

> **Definition:** A polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ splits over $F$ if it is a product of linear factors in $F[x]$.
>
> **Kronecker's theorem:** Let $f(x)\in F[x]$ where $F$ is a field. There exists a field $E$ containing $F$ over which $f(x)$ split.

What I did is:
$$x^4-x=x(x-1)(x^2+x+1).$$

I know that $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible, then $$(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)[x]/(x^2+x+1)=\{[0],[1],[1+x],[x]\}$$ is a field.

But I don't see I can conclude. Moreover, What do they want to say by "*adjoining a suitable root of $x^4-x$*" ?

Comment: You started by saying $x^2-x$, was this a typo?

Comment: I corrected it. Tks.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, when we adjoin a root to a field, it looks something like $\mathbb C=\mathbb R (i)$,  which is the closure of $\mathbb R$ when we add a root of $x^2+1=0$.   So here,  call your root of $x^2+x+1$ something,  so say $j$ satisfies $j^2+j+1=0$  mod 2.  Now,  look at the field $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z (j)$,  the elements of which are going to be $0,1,j,j+1$.  We get this is a field automatically since j is a root of an irreducible polynomial.  They may want you to actually work out the multiplication table/etc., but this shouldnt be too hard